# Node-sass error on RHEL 7.3

Tags: node.js, redhat, rhel7, node-sass

I get the following error when I try using the node-sass module in RHEL 7.3

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.2
    at module.exports (/home/pratyush/.gradle/node_setup/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pratyush/.gradle/node_setup/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pratyush/.gradle/node_setup/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:11:10)
:bcTaglibs:frontendCompileSass FAILED
```

Additional Information:

```
$ npm list -g node-sass
/home/pratyush/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib
├── node-sass@4.5.3 
├─┬ npm@5.0.0
│ └── node-sass@4.5.2 
└─┬ npm-check-updates@2.12.1
  └── node-sass@4.5.3
```

Could someone kindly help me resolve this? Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: NPM is trying to install `node-sass@4.5.2`, but the latest version (with proper support for your environment) is `node-sass@4.5.3` (which is _also_ installed, so not sure what's going on there). Do you have a dependency on 4.5.2 in your `package.json` perhaps?

Comment: It mentioned a bunch of 4.5.2 in package.json. I replaced them with 4.5.3, but it is still not working. My current package.json looks like https://pastebin.com/80KtNq6B

Comment: What exactly do you do that results in the error message?

Comment: The github URL is modified to 4.5.3 now..